# dynamic proxy in gwt

Tags: gwt, dynamic, binding, proxy

It is possible to create dynamic proxy in gwt? I want create library 
which changes behaviour of methods of some class (interface will be 
parameter), for example, when user call method of class implementing 
interface, it will return always String "abc". In java it would be 
something like this:

```
public class proxyHandler implements InvocationHandler { 
    private Object proxied; 
    public proxyHandler(Object proxied) { 
            this.proxied = proxied; 
    } 
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) 
                    throws Throwable { 
            return "abc"; 
    } 
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object object = new Object();
    Interface proxy = (Interface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            Interface.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class[] { Interface.class }, new proxyHandler(object));
    System.out.println(proxy.getName());
}
```

It is possible to do something like this in gwt (using deferred 
binding, whatever)? Thanks for any help

---

But I don't want to create code for MyClassOne or MyClassTwo. I want to create **dynamic proxy** - create one class (like proxyHandler in java example) which serves any type of object. I wany to  user give me an interface/class and I return him an object (like Interface proxy above) which he can use like normal class, but it would do something more.

---

GWT reflection is not updated from 2007. I reviewed also gwittir and gwt-ent but I cannot find any information how to dynamic proxies in them

Comment: I've merged your two unregistered accounts into this one, you should now be able to edit your question. Additionally, I merged the answers which should have been edits to your question back into your question. Please do not post an answer unless it is just that, an answer to this question. You should also now be able to use the comment facilities under each answer to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, GWT provides a way to "plug-in" you own implementation of classes and interfaces.
This is done via generators.

An example:

```
public class MyGenerator extends Generator{

    public String generate(TreeLogger logger, GeneratorContext context, 
                           java.lang.String typeName)
                           throws UnableToCompleteException {

        if (someCondition) {
            return "com.mypackage.MyClassOne"
        } else {
            return "com.mypackage.MyClassTwo"
        }
    }
}
```

then use it in your .gwt.xml file:

```
<generate-with class="com.mypackage.MyGenerator">  
    <when-type-assignable class="com.otherpackage.SomeClass" />  
</generate-with>
```

So when `SomeClass` is needed, generator will plug in `MyClassOne` or `MyClassTwo` based on some condition.

If you just need to replace one class/interface with your implementation, then you don't need to use generator, just use `<replace-with>` in your gwt module declaration:

```
<replace-with class="com.mypackage.MyClass">               
    <when-type-is class="com.otherpackage.SomeClass"/>
</replace-with>
```

Take a look at this blogposts for more info on generators:

http://blog.jdevelop.eu/2010/01/17/use-generators-to-create-boilerplate-code-in-gwt-20/

http://blog.jdevelop.eu/2010/01/17/use-generators-to-create-boilerplate-code-in-gwt-20/

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't: you don't have reflection on GWT. There exists [GWT reflection](http://gwtreflection.sourceforge.net/), but I never used it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GWT [AutoBeans](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean) for this. All non getter/setter methods are handled by Categories that can have method [Interceptors](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean#Interceptors):

*A category implementation may additionally declare an interceptor method to examine and possibly replace the return values of all non-void methods in the target interface:*

```
public static <T> T __intercept(AutoBean<?> bean, T returnValue) {
  // Do stuff
  return maybeAlteredReturnValue;
}
```